# Dataflow/apache beam: manage custom module dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a .py pipeline using apache beam that import another module (.py), that is my custom module.
I have a strucutre like this:

```
├── mymain.py
└── myothermodule.py
```

I import myothermodule.py in mymain.py like this:

```
import myothermodule
```

When I run locally on `DirectRuner`, I have no problem.
But when I run it on dataflow with `DataflowRunner`, I have an error that tells:

```
ImportError: No module named myothermodule
```

So I want to know what should I do if I whant this module to be found when running the job on dataflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run your pipeline remotely, you need to make any dependencies available on the remote workers too.
To do it you should put your module file in a Python package by putting it in a directory with a `__init__.py` file and creating a setup.py. It would look like this:

```
├── mymain.py
├── setup.py
└── othermodules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── myothermodule.py
```

And import it like this:

```
from othermodules import myothermodule
```

Then you can run you pipeline with the command line option `--setup_file ./setup.py`

A minimal setup.py file would look like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

The whole setup is documented [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies).

And a whole example using this can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset).

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said and I got this error: `ImportError: No module named othermodules`

Comment: Oh, I did a mistake, I named the `__init__.py` by `init.py` that's whay I got the error, It solves my problem so thank you so much